# I cannot select from city in MakeMyTrip wesite with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver

I cannot select from city in MakeMyTrip wesbite with Selenium WebDriver. It does not select the specified city. It should click on the specified city and display the city in the "from city" field.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

public class Makemytrip {

    public static void main(String[] args)  {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
        String actualTitle=" ";
        actualTitle=driver.getTitle();
        String url=driver.getCurrentUrl();
        System.out.println(url);
        String expectedTitle=actualTitle;
        if(actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
            System.out.println("Test pass");
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("Test fail");
        }
        WebElement roundtrip=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@class='label_text flight-trip-type']"));
        roundtrip.click();
        System.out.println("Select one way option");
        //driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/section/div/div/input[@id='hp-widget__sfrom']")).click();
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        List<WebElement> dd_menu=driver.findElements(By.xpath(".//ul[@id='ui-id-1']/li/div/p/span"));
        for(int i=0;i<dd_menu.size();i++){
            WebElement element=dd_menu.get(i);
            String innerhtml=element.getAttribute("innerHTML");
            if(innerhtml.contentEquals("Hyderabad, India             HYD" )){
                element.click();
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Values in list " +innerhtml);
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Input field is kind of autosuggestive dropdown here...you should use sendKeys here...one more thing use `explicit wait` here...I've used `Thread.sleep()` here...you can use `WebElement element = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("someid")));` Modify your code with following snippet..e.g.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException  {
            System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "D:\\Selenium\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe");
            WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
            driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/");
            String actualTitle=" ";
            actualTitle=driver.getTitle();
            String url=driver.getCurrentUrl();
            System.out.println(url);
            String expectedTitle=actualTitle;
            if(actualTitle.contentEquals(expectedTitle)){
                System.out.println("Test pass");
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Test fail");
            }
            WebElement roundtrip=driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//label[@class='label_text flight-trip-type']"));
            roundtrip.click();
            System.out.println("Select one way option");
            WebElement we = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//div/section/div/div/input[@id='hp-widget__sfrom']"));
            we.clear();
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            we.sendKeys("hyde");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
            we.sendKeys(Keys.RETURN);

            }
```

Comment: You are welcome. You can accept the answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue during testing. Whenever you try to open "makemytrip.com" site.
[Click here to check whether you are getting the same window](https://i.stack.imgur.com/laeH6.png)

Because of this menu, it block the entire WebElement to get access. To resolve this problem, follow the steps given below: -

1. Press Ctrl+Shift+i
2. Click on Inspect Pointer from the left top window of inspect tools.
3. Drag the pointer on window screen.
4. Select and copy the selected tagName's Xpath available on the inspect tool.
   [Here is the image of intermediate help for new learner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BALui.png)
5. Paste it on your respective working IDE as shown below. [Here is the working code to resolved the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ms5FI.png)

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

```
Please use the below code to solve the issue.     

String driverPath =  "C:\\geckodriver.exe";
            System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", driverPath);
            WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
            driver.manage().window().maximize();
            driver.get("https://www.makemytrip.com/flights/");
                Thread.sleep(2000);
            Actions act = new Actions(driver);
            
            WebElement ele= driver.findElement(By.xpath("//label[@for=\"fromCity\"]"));
            act.doubleClick(ele).perform();
```